# Why "coercion" and not "coertion" or "coersion"?

Tags: nouns, suffixes, word-formation

Usually, nouns coming from verbs end in the suffixes ***-tion*** or ***-sion***.

> After *-n* and *-r*, the ending can be ***-tion*** or ***-sion***. It's more likely to be ***-tion*** if the word's related to another one that ends in ***-t*** or ***-tain***, e.g. *assertion* (from *assert*) or *retention* (from *retain*).  (*[Lexico](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825044116/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/words-ending-in-sion-tion-and-cion)*)

Today I just came across ***coercion***, which comes from the verb *coerce*, so the suffix ***-cion*** follows ***-r-***. I also find it intriguing that its French version is ***[coercition](https://www.google.com/search?q=coercion%20in%20french&oq=coercion%20in%20french&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i15i22i30j0i22i30l3j0i390l2.5459j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)***.

Apparently there are only two words ending in ***-cion*** in English: ***coercion*** and ***suspicion***. Why are they an exception?

Comment: Rules like the ones you mention are always full of exceptions, because they generalize. In English, every word has its own etymology, and thence its own English spelling, courtesy of 600 years of printers and teachers who didn't want to change anything. So we have to learn it all individually.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes it's amazing... I looked more into _suspicion_ which comes from _suspicere_, though _inspection_ comes from _inspicere_, the same root. I am sure there must be a reason why in one word _spicere_ turned to _-spicion_ and in another ( actually in all the others) it turned into _-spection_.

Comment: Well, it **was** _spicere_ that turned into _suspicion_. The citation form for a Latin verb is always the infinitive, which is formed from the present stem (in this case, _spic-_.  What turned into _inspection_ was the perfect stem _spect-_ (meaning 'seen'). Latin verbs often have several stems; that's why you always quote the full four forms for a verb:  e.g, *spicio, spicere, spexi, spectus*

Comment: @JohnLawler If you could explain how this happened with coercion and add this comment to the answer, I would accept it. This is it. I knew this couldn't be random.

Comment: Different parts of verbs got borrowed and fused together elsewhere. No predicting, no explaining; it's like distributing family junk after each death, over several dozen generations. They may be recognizable, but who knows what hands (or mouths) they came through? Local randomness is the norm, but patterns, when they show up, sometimes show things. That's why historical linguists **insist** on regular sound correspondences, and plenty of them.

Comment: Oh, and what happened to _coercion_ is just spelling conventions. They change and they were never codified or enforced widely. Printing solidified them somewhat, but spelchek is likely wiping the slate.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ok :) I give up then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is an exception from the more common *-tion -sion* spellings, retaining the original  French spelling.

[-tion](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-tion#etymonline_v_13348)

> syllable formed when the word-forming element -ion (from Latin -io) is fixed to a base or to another suffix ending in -t or -te. ***In Middle English, in words via Old French, it often was -cion (in coercion and suspicion, however, the -c- belongs to the base).***

[-cion](https://www.etymonline.com/word/coercion#etymonline_v_28265)

> It defies the usual pattern where Middle English -cion reverts to Latin type and becomes -tion.  [OED].

Etymonline

Comment: Even modern French doesn't have it. Most of their nouns  coming from verbs end in _**-tion**_ or _**-ssion**_. Spanish _[-cion]_ and Portuguese _[çaõ]_ have retained the _**c**_ in this Latin suffix...